# How to remove zero from number 452.91zero and convert into float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe(name data) below

[image]

In row 15 I have highlighted a column (Amount) having one of the values as 452.91zero .How to convert the column into float by removing zero from 452.91zero and converting into float.

Comment: For amount in brackets, are they negative numbers ?   Need to convert to negative values ?

Answer (score -1):

I am going to give other solution that I suppose can solve too.
Why don't use REGEX?

Below is the code...

```
import re



 column = "452.91zero"
 column = re.sub('[a-zA-Z]*', '', column)
 print(column)
```